# Java LinkedList Node Manipulation

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I want to implement Aaron William's Multiset Permutation iteration algorithm in Java. [Algorithm Whitepaper](http://webhome.csc.uvic.ca/~haron/CoolMulti.pdf). The important take away is that the algorithm uses a linked list to represent the multiset, and involves keeping several pointers to various linked list nodes, tracking the head node, and getting the next node from a pointer.

**I understand that the built in LinkedList implementation does not offer these features.** I also recognize that rolling my own linked list implementation is trivial for this task. However, it strikes me that writing all the boilerplate code to honor the List interface is less trivial -- say I want to sort my list with Collections.Sort! It also strikes me that there would be some level of storage duplication from whatever collection's input to store my separate list implementation.

My question: **is there *another* native Java data structure that DOES provides these features?** Surely my goal is far from unique enough to require my own linked list implementation.

Comment: I don't think there are any, even to implement sorting algorithms is way better to implement your own linked list, because that way you can manipulate your nodes as wished. Java's linked list isn't what you need.

Comment: The thing about Java's `LinkedList` is it's **not designed to be a linked list.** It is there as an **another implementation of `List` interface**. It's named `LinkedList` cause it **uses linked list data structure** but that is all since **you don't have access to the actual `Node`'s**.

Comment: Something I learned during my higher degree is that instead of reinventing the wheel, you can try emailing the author for his original source code? That way you can avoid creating your own and can also express interest in the author's work hence growing your network.

Comment: There's already a linked-list in the standard API, it doesn't make sense for there to be another one that's essentially the same. You can find an implementation of the standard LinkedList class online ([example](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/LinkedList.java)) to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Java LinkedList node entries are not public so it is not suitable for some use cases, i.e. finding, removing or adding a certain element at a certain position is expensive. I had a similar problem where I needed node access to efficiently remove an item and push it to the top of the list.

I came up with a specialized double linked list implementation. I store the node structure directly in the elements, i.e. the elements are derived from the nodes. This has the advantage that manipulating the list does not require any memory allocation. However, the downside is that an element can only be part of one list. If you don't want to store the node in your elements just create a wrapper node class that holds an element...

Implementation: [DoubleLinkedList](https://github.com/czeidler/fejoajava/blob/master/src/main/java/org/fejoa/library/support/DoubleLinkedList.java)
and the test:
[DoubleLinkedListTest](https://github.com/czeidler/fejoajava/blob/master/src/main/java/org/fejoa/tests/DoubleLinkedListTest.java)